# creating a xaml with xslt

Tags: xml, xaml, xslt, namespaces

Im trying to create an xsl template of the xaml Line element.

This is what i have so far:

```
... 

<xsl:call-template name="Line">
  <xsl:with-param name="xOne" select="70"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="xTwo" select="905"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="yOne" select="500"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="yTwo" select="500"/>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="Line">
    <xsl:param name="xOne"/>
    <xsl:param name="xTwo"/>
    <xsl:param name="yOne"/>
    <xsl:param name="yTwo"/>
    <Line xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      Stroke="red"
      StrokeThickness="2"
      X1="$xOne"
      X2="$xTwo"
      Y1="<xsl:value-of select="number($yOne)"/>" <!-- example: not working -->
      Y2="$yTwo"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Questions:

- Is there a better way to manage those **namespaces**?
- The parameters $xOne, $xTwo, ... are not working. As far as I know xslt i should implement them like this : `<xsl:value-of select="number($xOne)"/>` but thats not possible because of the way I try to implement them.

I hope someone with more experience of xslt and xaml could help me? :)

*I'm using xsl v1.0*

ty in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can put namespace declaration in root node, i.e.:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>
```

So then you can simply write, without adding namespaces:

```
<Line
```

Use `{}` to set attribute values, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template name="Line">
    <xsl:param name="xOne"/>
    <xsl:param name="xTwo"/>
    <xsl:param name="yOne"/>
    <xsl:param name="yTwo"/>
    <Line
        Stroke="red"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        X1="{$xOne}"
        X2="{$xTwo}"
        Y1="{$yOne}"
    Y2="{$yTwo}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

> ***Is there a better way to manage those namespaces?***

You can add the namespace declarations to the stylesheet root element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

and then use the prefix where required, like:

```
<xsl:template name="Line">
    <!-- ... -->
    <x:Line />
</xsl:template>
```

where prefix is not used,  the default namespace will be considered.

---

> ***The parameters $xOne, $xTwo, ... are not working***

Learn about [AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) and use:

```
X1="{$xOne}"
```